# Remove single Quotes in prolog (Html - Prolog)

Tags: html, prolog, swi-prolog

Hello I have problem in my project !

We have a Knowledge Base in prolog and we must make a web app to add,edit or remove rules from KB. My problem is when I add the rule (using html) in KB using this code:

```
addRule(_Request):-
    format('Content-type: text/html~n~n'),
    print_html([
        '<html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/materialize/css/materialize.css">
                <script src="/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
                <title>Rules</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                    <h4>Εισαγωγή κανόνα</h4>
                    <form action="/addition" method="POST">
                        Δώσε τα δεδομένα :  
                        <div class="input-field inline">
                            <input type="text" name="newRuleData" class="validate">
                        </div>
                        Δώσε τις προυποθέσεις :  
                        <div class="input-field inline">
                            <input type="text" name="newRuleCon" class="validate">
                        </div>
                        Δώσε το αποτέλεσμα :   
                        <div class="input-field inline">
                            <input type="text" name="newRuleResult" class="validate">
                        </div>

                        <button class="black-text btn waves-effect waves-light green" type="submit" name="action">ADD</button>

                        <br><br><br>
                    </form> 
            </body>
        </html>'                  
    ]).
```

When i press ADD button goes here:

```
addition(Request):-
    http_parameters(Request,[
            newRuleData(RuleData,[default('NULL')]),
            newRuleCon(RuleCon,[default('NULL')]),
            newRuleResult(RuleResult,[default('NULL')])
    ]),
    %προσθήκη max_ruleId 
    max_ruleId(MaxID),
    NewMaxID is MaxID+1,
    atom_concat(rid,NewMaxID,NewRuleId),
    retract( max_ruleId(MaxID) ),
    asserta( max_ruleId(NewMaxID) ),

    %προσθήκη στα Rules
    rules(List),
    append(List,[NewRuleId],NewList),
    retract(rules(List)),
    asserta(rules(NewList)),
    assertz((rule(NewRuleId,RuleData,Answer):- RuleCon,Answer=RuleResult)),
    saveRules.
```

After, I go in my KB and i see this:

```
rule(rid15, '[LabValues,Saturation,Nitrate,Oligochaetes,Sediments,Hydrothio,Methanio,Substrates,SmellWater]', A) :-
'LabValues = nai, atom_number(Saturation,Sat), Sat>100',
A='Evales poli megalo koresmo'.
```

The rule must look like this:

```
rule(rid15, [LabValues,Saturation,Nitrate,Oligochaetes,Sediments,Hydrothio,Methanio,Substrates,SmellWater], A) :-
LabValues = nai, atom_number(Saturation,Sat), Sat>100,
A='Evales poli megalo koresmo'.
```

I want to remove the quotes but I can't.

### EDIT

Currently using [term_to_atom/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_to_atom/2) to remove the quotes but it gives me this in my KB

```
rule(rid21, [_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _], B) :-
     true, 
     atom_number(_, A), 
     A>100, 
     B='Evales poli megalo koresmo'.
```

Comment: i am sorry my friend i want to remove quotes  
this :'[LabValues,Saturation,Nitrate,Oligochaetes,Sediments,Hydrothio,Methanio,Substrates,SmellWater]' to this : [LabValues,Saturation,Nitrate,Oligochaetes,Sediments,Hydrothio,Methanio,Substrates,SmellWater] i think its the same if i convert it

Comment: i have use the term_to_atom/2 it remove the quotes but it give me 
this result : [_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _]

Comment: Well, they are capitalized, so they look like singleton variables to Prolog. You don't want to "remove the single quotes," you want to _parse the string_, which is a little different.

Comment: However this should work `['LabValues','Saturation','Nitrate','Oligochaetes','Sediments','Hydrothio','Methanio','Substrates','SmellWater']`

Comment: i am trying to analyse the atoms but nothing

Comment: Of interest: [Why It’s Nice to be Quoted: Quasiquoting for Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/publications/quasiquoting.pdf) Jan is an author so worth the read. Reading now, not sure if applies.

Comment: i use the term_string/2
and it give me this in my KB
rule(rid21, [_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _], B) :-
 true,
 atom_number(_, A),
 A>100,
 B='Evales poli megalo koresmo'.

With the same values.

Comment: Of interest: [http_read_data/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=http_read_data/3) and [http_convert_data/4](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=http_client%3Ahttp_convert_data/4)

Comment: Of interest: [Tutorial - Creating Web Applications in SWI-Prolog](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/index.html)

Comment: Of interest: [SWI-Prolog HTTP support](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/http.html%27))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found solution !!!

```
%We take the request from Form

addition(Request):-
member(method(post),Request),!,
http_parameters(Request,
[
    newRuleData(RuleData,[length>0, string]),
    newRuleCon(RuleCon,[length>0, string]),
    newRuleResult(RuleResult,[length>0, string])
]),
addNewRule(RuleData,"Answer",RuleCon,RuleResult),
format('Content-type: text/html~n~n'),
print_html([
    '<html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/materialize/css/materialize.css">
            <script src="/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>Επιτυχία</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="navbar-fixed">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav-wrapper teal lighten-2">
                        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">WebApp της εργασίας 2</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="container center">
                <h4>Η εισαγωγή του κανόνα πέτυχε.</h4> 
                <br><br>
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" href="http://localhost:8000/update"><i class="material-icons left" >arrow_back</i>Back</a>
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" href="http://localhost:8000"><i class="material-icons left" >home</i>Home</a> 
                <br><br><br>
                <h3>Μάνος Κουτουλάκης 4002</h3>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>'                   
]).
```

When I took the data from my page I use the `addNewRule` and here we make processes. the `max_ruleId/1` and the `rules/1` coming from my KB the first one have inside the sum of rules and the other one it's a `list` with all id's inside.

```
addNewRule(RuleData,RuleResultVariableName,RuleCon,RuleResult):-
   %προσθήκη max_ruleId 
   max_ruleId(MaxID),
   NewMaxID is MaxID+1,
   atom_concat(rid,NewMaxID,NewRuleId),
   retract( max_ruleId(MaxID) ),
   asserta( max_ruleId(NewMaxID) ),

   %προσθήκη στα Rules
   rules(List),
   append(List,[NewRuleId],NewList),
   retract(rules(List)),
   asserta(rules(NewList)),
   atom_string(NewRuleId, SRuleId),
   string_list_concat(
      [
        "rule(", SRuleId, ",", RuleData, ",", RuleResultVariableName, 
        "):-",
        RuleCon, ",", RuleResultVariableName, "='", RuleResult, "'"
      ],
      StringRule
  ),
  term_string(Rule, StringRule),
  assertz(Rule),
  saveRules.
```

The predicate to concat the String:

```
string_list_concat([], S):- 
  S = "".
string_list_concat([H], S):- !, 
  string(H), 
  S = H.
string_list_concat([H|T], S):- 
  string_list_concat([H|T], "", S).
string_list_concat([H|T], Acc, S):- 
  string(H),
  string_concat(Acc, H, Acc1),
  string_list_concat(T, Acc1, S).
string_list_concat([], Acc, S):- 
  S = Acc.
```

Essentially I take the inputs from **HTML** (Using [http_parametres/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=http_parameters/2)), I union all inputs in one String list using `string_list_concat`
and finally to assert the rule into my KB I use [term_string/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_string/2)
to converse the string to term and the Quotes has gone. maybe my question should have been different.

Comment: You need to explain what you did. Just posting code is not really an acceptable answer because people have to look for the differences to learn something. StackOverflow is about learning, not just getting answers.

Comment: I hope my explanation will help !

Comment: It is better, but I still have to read your code to understand it. Not to worry, when I first started using StackOverflow I was not as good as I am now.